# Find formula that produces desired graph

Tags: probability, functions, binomial-distribution

Let's say we have an urn of balls of size $n$, Each ball has probability $p$ of being red.

I take a sample from this urn without replacement and calculate the probability of having at least a majority of balls that are red using the cumulative binomial distribution:

$$P_n=\sum_{i=n/2}^{n}\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

If I calculate this for different sample sizes i get the following figure:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/fig1.png]

I would like to modify the above formula to produce the inverse of this figure which would look like this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/fig2.pdf

I'm sure there is an obvious change to this formula that will produce the second figure but I was not able to figure it out.

I tried $1$ minus the formula but that does not produce the desired result.

Any ideas?
Any other formula that has an interpretation in terms of sampling from an urn and probability of choosing correct AND produces figure2  is fine.

Comment: Not necessarily. Think of the same formula but instead of i=n/2 let i=n*2/3. In that case you also get probabilities smaller than p.

Comment: It is possible to put images inline.

Comment: Not without a reputation of 10.